# Drupal 7 Views 3 Field Template

Tags: drupal, view

I have searched the world over for an answer to this question.  This is well documented in Views 2, but there is nothing mentioned about Views 3.

I am simply trying to access other field values in a field template. Can anyone clearly explain how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

In the field template file, you'll have access to the `$row` variable that contains all fields for the current row. Use `dsm($row)` to check out its contents.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for `views-view-field.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-field.tpl.php/7):

You should have access to the full `$view` object in which you can drill down to any field that you need.

Comment: Can you help me understand how to drill down to a field?  I checked the documentation you cited and I'm still not sure how to do it.

Comment: @user1012117 I suggest using the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to help you learn Drupal development.  You can use `dpm($view)` with devel to print out the `$view` object to see what's it in and how to get at certain data that you're looking for.

Comment: Yes - I have the devel module installed and have been looking at the information displayed. Unfortunately, I've been trying for three days to make this work.  See my post at drupal: http://drupal.org/node/1160706. I've tried hundreds of combinations and clearly I'm not understanding something. Specifically, here is what I have:

Comment: A view with 5 fields - I'm trying to override the line_item_title field and create an IF statement with the other fields.  If the field field_student_name exists, it should display instead of line_item_title. The IF statement isn't the problem. I can't get that field_student_name value into my line_item_title template in the first place. Any guidance would be massively appreciated - wits end.

Comment: BTW, my drupal comment is under bpeicher

Comment: You should be able to use `$view->style_plugin->rendered_fields[$view->row_index][$field_id]` as merlinofchaos noted.  I've just changed `$row_index` to `$view->row_index`